# Correlation / clustering over lognormal data

Tags: distributions, correlation, clustering, lognormal-distribution

I'm working with some financial data and it turns out my data is pretty much lognormal distributed.

The question I have is, which produces "better" results:
using plain data to find correlation / clusters or should I work on logarithmized data?

For example, over plain data I get correlation of 0.43 while over log data the correlation is 0.59. For clusters it also seems they get better separated using log data.

Scatterplot over plain and log data:

[image]

[image]

And histogram of log of one of tha variables:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is *sensible* to compare correlation values on different scales. It's apples and oranges.

But judging from your plots, i'd expect the results to be better after log or sqrt transformations.

You should still find an argument why this transformation is **meaningful/sensible for your domain** though. This cannot be solved with mathematics.

Comment: Maths and statistics are really not my strong points.  
That said, there is 0.6 correlation between var and log(var), which means they do kinda measure the same thing, right? And based on that, maybe, comparing correlation on different scales is sensible?  
Anyway, what would make a good argument why the transformation is sensible for a domain?  
Where could I find example arguments for other domains, to see if the argument applies?

Comment: It is not random, but that doesn't mean it is more "correct". Compute the correlation of x to exp(x), what do you get? I just took a sample of 10000 uniform randoms, and x to exp(x) had a correlation of 0.92, while x to log(x) only had a correlation of 0.863... so just based on the correlation, you cannot argue that one transformation is better than the other.